# Disable item click and enable onclick of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

here is my layout xml.If relativelayout click works that is also fine.Not getting any click events other than item clicks.

```
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutItems"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewDivider">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/item_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

               </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some different ways to do it. The first way is to do like this:

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
 new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, recyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // do whatever
  }

  @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // do whatever
  }
})
```

);

Or you can do it in a ViewHolder.

1. We will need a listener interface.

   ```
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
          public void onClick(View view, int position);
            }
   ```
2. In your ViewHolder class in your RecyclerView adapter, implement View.OnClickListener, bind the listener to the view. In the onClick method, call the onClick method of the interface OnItemClickListener. This should be passed in from your RecycyclerView’s constructor. The actual implementation of the onclick event will be from an activity or fragment that contains this RecyclerView. The important line here is clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition()); where clickListener is a global variable in your RecyclerView class, again it should’ve passed in from your RecyclerView’s constructor.

   ```
       public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
       public TextView cityName;
       public ViewHolder(View view) {
         super(view);
         cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
         itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener
      }
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition()); // call the onClick in the OnItemClickListener
   ```

   }
   }
3. The onClick implementation in the Activity class, the important line here is mAdapter.setClickListener(this); and the onClick method. The onClick method gets triggered from the ViewHolder’s onClick method in your RecyclerView class, which passes the view and position of the clicked item.

   ```
       public class CityActivity extends Activity implements ItemClickListener {

       private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
       private CityAdapter mAdapter;
       private List<City> cities;

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_city);
        cities = CityManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getCites();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mAdapter = new CityAdapter(cities, R.layout.row_city, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setClickListener(this); // Bind the listener
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        // The onClick implementation of the RecyclerView item click
        final City city = cities.get(position);
         Intent i = new Intent(this, CityviewActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("city", city.name);
         i.putExtra("desc", city.description);
         i.putExtra("image", city.imageName);
         Log.i("hello", city.name);
         startActivity(i);
       }
      }
   ```

Comment: Please read the question I don't want the on item click . I just need Recyclerview's  or relativelayout's  onclick